# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf embed Tailwind CSS inside HTML for external service?

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, tailwind-css, spring-thymeleaf

I have a spring boot project and I'm using TailwindCSS. The issue is, while putting

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{~/css/main.css}" />
```

Works fine when I want to access the HTML file locally from my instance, the issue is I convert these HTMLs into PDFs using API2PDF service.

So, the service is unable to read the CSS and the HTML comes out to be without any styling.

How can I make sure the generated Tailwind CSS is sent along with the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I would include the CSS within the HTML file using the `<style>` tag